# Can't figure out how to make toggleClass work properly with window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I load my page when it is over 860px wide the script works the way I want it to. It does not have the `.open` class on the child `ul` tag of `li.parent` class. It also adds that class when I make the page smaller.

However, I noticed when I go from the page being smaller to larger, the `.open` class still hangs around. And if I click on the `li.parent`, it throws off the script and it no longer works when the page is smaller.

Here is my script.

```
$(window).resize(function (){
    if ( $(window).width() < 860 ) {
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('li.parent').click(function(){
                $(this).find('ul').toggleClass('open');
            });
        });
    }
    else {
        $('ul#primary-nav').removeAttr('style');
        $('li.parent').find('ul').removeClass('open');
    }
});
```

Other scripts in the same document. Maybe they are causing a conflict?

```
// Mobile Menu Slide Toggle 
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.show_nav').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        jQuery('#primary-nav').slideToggle();
    });
});

// For Menu Caret
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('ul#primary-nav li').has('ul').addClass('parent');
});
```

Some of the CSS

```
ul#primary-nav li.parent ul {display: none;}

ul#primary-nav li.parent ul.open {display: block;}
```

Some of the HTML

```
<a href="#primary-nav" class="show_nav"><img src="images/hamburger-lines-white.svg" alt="Menu" width="25" height="25"></a> 
<ul id="primary-nav">
    <li><a href="#">About</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Facilities</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Tennis</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Classes</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Calendar</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Newsletter</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Home Owners</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Board of Directors</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Architectural Committee</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Documents and Forms</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Been trying to figure this out for a while and looked all over this site. Could really use some help.

Comment: This is what media queries are for.

Comment: Don't do it in JavaScript, use css.

Comment: Welcome to SO! The problem with your code is that what it does is that "It adds a click event listener every time the resize event is fired" and I don't think this is what you want to do

Comment: **What you want to do needs to be done in CSS using media queries, not in Javascript.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget the jQuery and use a media query.

```
ul#primary-nav li.parent ul {display: none;}

@media only screen and (min-width: 860px) {
    ul#primary-nav li.parent ul {display: block;}
}
```

Comment: Probably should have clarified a little bit more. I am using the jQuery in order to show/hide using toggleClass on the navigation when the page width is below 860. Here is what I have so far. [link](http://mikemaloney.me/rbstc/) It works perfectly fine when the page is smaller or just when you load the page wider than 860px as well. The issue happens when you resize the page to the smaller size and click on the link with a sub menu. Thanks -Mike

Comment: Again, forget the jQuery for any of this. This should all be done using css. Delete every line of jQuery you have so far and look into doing it with css :hover and media queries.

Comment: Woops yeah, thanks. Was overthinking and over complicating it.